# Setting names for attributes in properties in json returned by postgresql

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openlayers, geojson, json

I am trying to make a webmapping app that uses on the server side node.js and postgresql(PostGIS). what I am doing is retrieving data from the Postgresql database using node.js and sending the result in JSON (geoJSON) format to Openlayers 3, using this query :

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc)
FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features
    FROM (
    SELECT 'Feature' As type
    , ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.geometry)::json As geometry
    , row_to_json((attribute1, attribute2, attributeN)) As properties
    FROM myTable As lg   ) As f )  As fc;
```

my problem is that in the JSON data retrieved the `"properties"` are defined as `"f1", "f2", "fN"` instead of the actual names of the attributes, I saw this answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27732/set-names-to-attributes-when-creating-json-with-row-to-json) in dba.stackexchange but it doesn't consider the fact that the attributes are within the `"properties"`

- How to set the actual names of my attributes in the JSON returned instead of `"f1", "f2", "fN"` ?

I could get used to calling my properties in OL3 with `"f1", "f2", "fN"` since I am working alone on this app but that would be an obedient and kind of lazy solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to use the `json_build_object` function.

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc)
FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features
    FROM (
    SELECT 'Feature' As type
    , ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.geometry)::json As geometry
    , json_build_object(
                       'attribute1', attribute1, 
                       'attribute2', attribute2,
                       'attributeN', attributeN)) As properties
    FROM myTable As lg   ) As f )  As fc;
```